# Dependency Injection Container, class parameters

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am trying to code a very simple dependency injection container.

So far i have the following (its not much but a start to understanding):

```
class DiContainer
{
    private $_parameters;

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_parameters[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_parameters[$key])) {
            $class = $this->_parameters[$key]; 
            return new $class; 
        }
    }
}
```

What happens if a class needs some parameters?

So if I have:

```
class A {

  public function __construct($params, $params2) {

  }
}
```

How would i instantiate that through the service container?

Answer (score 1):

With reflection

```
$reflectedClass = new ReflectionClass($classname);
$instance = $reflectedClass->newInstanceArgs($constructorArguments);
```

See [ReflectionClass:newInstanceArgs()](http://php.net/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs)

Comment: Im not following. Sorry. How would i get those arguments into the container

Comment: Seems you didn't read the link (or anything related to reflection)... I cannot say very much about it: The two lines are really everything needed.

Comment: Yes i understand what the reflection side of it does.  But when i instantiate a class from outside my container how do the parameters get in

Comment: If you instanciate it _outside_ your container, how does it affect your container? Beside this: `new MyClass($arg1, $arg2)`

Comment: I thought i would be using the container like so $requestedClass = $container->requestedClass and the __set method would create the object for me  but i just wasnt sure how to pass parameters or let the container know what parameters are needed - i probably need to read more on dependency injection containers as this is just not clicking for me

Comment: With `__get()` you can't because you obviously can't pass additional parameters except the propertyname. You could pass it before you need them, for example in `__set()`. I recommend to have a look at an existing container implementation (like Symfony2, or ZF2) to get an inspiration. When the learning effect is not the point you should consider to use one of this.